# How unshare makes possible to use chroot without real root?

Tags: linux, chroot, linux-capabilities, linux-namespaces

`chroot` needs `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` according to the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html). The `unshare` command [uses chroot](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/unshare.c#L644).

The command `unshare -UrR newroot/` will work without being run as `root`, which makes sense since the `-r` flag makes us `root` inside the namespace, giving us the `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability.

The problem begins when `unshare -UR newroot/` doesn't require being run as `root`, while `unshare -U chroot newroot/` will give me the `Operation not permitted` error. So in the first, I am not asking for being `root` inside the user namespace, and the second is the same but trying to do it manually.

Checking the [code](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/unshare.c#L643-L648), the only thing that happens when using `-R` is setting the `newroot` to `optarg`, so I can't understand why in one example this works, and in the other, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `unshare(2)` is called first, and it's passed `CLONE_NEWUSER` as one of the flags bceause of `-U`.  The manual remarks about that flag:

> Unshare the user namespace, so that the calling process is moved into a new user namespace which  is  not shared  with  any  previously existing process.  As with the child process created by `clone(2)` with the `CLONE_NEWUSER` flag, the caller obtains a full set of capabilities in the new namespace.

Now that the process has a full set of capabilities in the new namespace, it can call `chroot(2)`.  Note that that call occurs before the process with mapped IDs is invoked, so at that point, the process is still privileged in the new user namespace.  The capabilities are dropped upon the `execve` call to start the new process.

That's why your `chroot` command fails: because it lacks permissions, whereas the `unshare` command is still privileged before it invokes any process.